# Webstorm 10 won't run my HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, webstorm

This is my code I'm using to test Webstorm, and when I try to run it, it goes to Chrome and gives me a 404 Not Found error. Why is this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Sample text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The server can't find the requested file. Need more info to figure out why.

Comment: I just clicked the run button in Webstorm

Comment: Try to delete the Run configuration and create a new one. Or alternatively, check that the port specified in the Run configuration is the same as in Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger - Built-in server port.